# Find partial match between two columns and return a third column

Tags: excel, match, formula, matching, partial

I'd like to create a formula that looks for a partial match in two columns in two different Worksheets, and if there is a partial match between the two columns, it returns the value of a different column in Worksheet 2.

Example:

```
Sheet 1 Column A:
Dev
Tim
Jon

Sheet 2 Column A:
Development
Timothy
Jonathan
```

If there is a partial match as there is in these fields, I want it to return the value from Sheet 2 Column B.

Currently I have the following formula:

```
=INDEX(ValueIWant,MATCH(A1,ColumntoPartialMatchAgainst,0))
```

However, this returns the "ValueIWant" field only when there is an exact match.

How can I modify this formula to work with even a partial match?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&"*",`Sheet 2`!A:B,2,0)
```

Note this deliberately only adds a wildcard (`*`) to the end of the Sheet 1 values to reduce the risk of a match with something like `estimate`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result you should concatenate wildcard(s) to the value to search. In your formula, instead of `A1`, please try:

`A1 & "*"`  - if you want to match only the beginning of array values (like in your sample data)

`"*" & A1 & "*` - to match any part of array values